# How get Document.write working for this anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Hi Everyone this is my first post to the forum.
I am trying to use following code

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?    String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p})
```

parameters:

```
p = '16 2d=2A;16 26=2A;16 4j=2A;16 93=2A;16 3m=2A;1h 9i(c,d){8q(c);1i(d==2A){16 e="47://34."+3B+"/2h/4S/54/3A.2S?3i=6p";3b.3a.35({3c:"4C",4E:e},1h(a){16 b=a.3A.7C;4l=b;6h(b)})}1T{6h(d)}7m()};1h 8q(a){16 b=7i();16 c=\'\';c+=\'<W 1m="9J" 1k="3h" A="r:3o; v-r:3o; 6:F; v-6:F; J-6:7; K:0; I:0 4; L:0; C:V; M:4; 11:4; G:1P; G:1U; u:9y; Z:8P; z-1n:2i; N:t; D:t; H:4; 8-9:u; O-9:1b; X-Y:7; U-13:7; q:1; P:Q(q=R); S:1l;">\';'
a=62
c = 696
k = '||||none||height|normal|text|align|||||||||||||||||opacity|width||visible|left|min|||||style|wjQuery|display|overflow||auto|position|background|border|line|padding|margin|float|visibility|vertical|filter|alpha|100|cursor|font|word|block|div|white|space|top|static|clear|span|wrap|pointer|this|var|attr|24px|img|spacing|baseline|common|src|png|title|color|function|if|img_path|class|default|'.split('|')
e = 0
r = {}
```

I want to use `document.write()` method to show the output of the function after passing the parameters. But I am not sure how to pass it using the anonymous function call.  Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you give the function a name so that you can call it?

Comment: Is this something called evil script?

Comment: Giving name is not in my hand as the same is part of js file provided by third party. All I can do is pass the parameters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `eval` with `q =`, then call `q(p,a,c,k,e,r)` and look at the output, which is a *String* of the code, and beautifies to

```
var 2d = 2A;
var 26 = 2A;
var 4j = 2A;
var 93 = 2A;
var 3m = 2A;

function 9i(c, d) {
    8q(c);
    if (d == 2A) {
        var e = "47://34." + 3B + "/2h/4S/54/3A.2S?3i=6p";
        3b.3a.35({
            3c: "4C",
            4E: e
        }, function (a) {
            var b = a.3A.7C;
            4l = b;
            6h(b)
        })
    }
    1T {
        6h(d)
    }
    7m()
};

function 8q(a) {
    var b = 7i();
    var c = '';
    c += '<div 1m="9J" class="3h" style="width:3o; min-width:3o; height:auto; min-height:auto; line-height:normal; padding:0; border:0 none; margin:0; display:block; float:none; clear:none; position:1P; position:1U; left:9y; top:8P; z-1n:2i; visibility:visible; overflow:visible; background:none; text-align:left; vertical-align:baseline; white-space:normal; word-wrap:normal; opacity:1; filter:alpha(opacity=100); cursor:default;">';
```

Notice that the last function is not terminated correctly and both functions are named illegally.

Comment: Yeah thanks your code works for pointing out my error in termination.

Comment: Although I can not change function name. I awarded you best answer for pointing out my mistake. I will still have to use Mr. Barmar;s method to implement the same. I hope Mr. Barmar does not mind me awarding you the points

Comment: I've got rep to spare :)

Comment: I like this answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can call an anonymous function using an IIFE (Immediately Executing Function Expression). Wrap the function in parentheses (this isn't always necessary, but it can't hurt), and follow it with the arguments in parentheses:

```
var p = '16 2d=2A;16 26=2A;16 4j=2A;16 93=2A;16 3m=2A;1h 9i(c,d){8q(c);1i(d==2A){16 e="47://34."+3B+"/2h/4S/54/3A.2S?3i=6p";3b.3a.35({3c:"4C",4E:e},1h(a){16 b=a.3A.7C;4l=b;6h(b)})}1T{6h(d)}7m()};1h 8q(a){16 b=7i();16 c=\'\';c+=\'<W 1m="9J" 1k="3h" A="r:3o; v-r:3o; 6:F; v-6:F; J-6:7; K:0; I:0 4; L:0; C:V; M:4; 11:4; G:1P; G:1U; u:9y; Z:8P; z-1n:2i; N:t; D:t; H:4; 8-9:u; O-9:1b; X-Y:7; U-13:7; q:1; P:Q(q=R); S:1l;">\';';
var a=62;
var c = 696;
var k = '||||none||height|normal|text|align|||||||||||||||||opacity|width||visible|left|min|||||style|wjQuery|display|overflow||auto|position|background|border|line|padding|margin|float|visibility|vertical|filter|alpha|100|cursor|font|word|block|div|white|space|top|static|clear|span|wrap|pointer|this|var|attr|24px|img|spacing|baseline|common|src|png|title|color|function|if|img_path|class|default|'.split('|');
var e = 0;
var r = {};
document.write((function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?    String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p})(p,a,c,k,e,r));
```